# Word for "becoming more and more distant"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> That night, Mary and Tom discussed about Tom's gradual __

Basically, I'm looking for a word that means *distancement*. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about ***withdrawal***

Comment: Lack of detail, what do you mean by "distancement"? A word, which is nonstandard, (it should be "distance") do you mean they are [**growing apart**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grow-apart)? Do you need a single word at all cost? Can an idiom do just as well? Do you want to convey that the *growing apart* is one-sided?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## dis·en·gage·ment

ˌdisənˈɡājmənt

> noun
> 1.
> the action or process of withdrawing from involvement in a particular activity, situation, or group.
> "their steady disengagement from politics and politicians"
> 2.
> emotional detachment; objectivity.
> "contemporary criticism can afford neutral disengagement"

Source: entry in [Oxford online dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/disengagement)

Comment: My source was dictionary.com, which probably comes from Oxford.

Comment: Since Oxford seems to be the root source, I have edited the answer to cite it as the source.

Answer (score -3):

**Distancization**

[How does it show its distancization from earlier sources?](https://kavvanah.wordpress.com/2015/02/08/interview-with-prof-moulie-vidas/)

Noun form of **to distancize**. For this see

> So, just saying, you can enjoy it, but be aware of its shortcomings, and distancize yourself from some aspects.

([Source](https://www.gog.com/forum/general_archive/are_there_any_females_on_here/post204))

> Keywords in media coverage of the Horn of Africa: hunger, violence, conflict-do they proximize or distancize?

([Source](https://mobile.twitter.com/monika_weronika/status/96396997761826816))

Notice from the same source  this can refer to metaphorical rather than spatial distance:

> for me in/ou[t]  are clearly spatial relations but not primarily distance, which is a (metaphorical) derivative there

Last, see

> it's imperative to distancize oneself from it as ostensibly as possible, in order to avoid suspicion, "contamination", etc

([Source](https://www.gog.com/forum/general/gay_character_in_mk_x))

Comment: Distancize? I can't find any evidence that this word actually exists. The fact that someone on Twitter has said it doesn't make it a real word.